# How to pass value from activity selected item to previous AlertDialog

Tags: android

The scenario are

1.Open DocActivity which has button,the cosign button show Alert Dialog

2.In the AlertDialog,it will link to people search Activity.

3.User will select item to go back to map value to AlertDialog cosign people field.

My Problem is, in DocActivity how to get the intent data from people search?

I think to override onActivityResult is correct ?

Below code is People Search Activity ,i try to turn back to DocActivity

```
                    selectPosition = position;
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    selectEmployee = peoples[position].toString();

                    Intent passIntent = new Intent(CompanyContactActivity.this, DocActivity.class);
                    // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
                    passIntent.putExtra("employeeInfo", selectEmployee);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, passIntent);
                    finish();

                }
```

Comment: post code ...don't post snapshot of code

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` before `finish()`in people activity?

Comment: Yes i call that.  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, passIntent);

Comment: Can you post how you start the People Activity?